# 4K 60Hz - on Macbook Pro 2015, 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, thunderbolt-display, 4k

I've read many articles saying that you should use a Thunderbolt 2 (MiniDP) to Display Port connector. However, the monitor (Dell S2722QC) does not have a Display Port connector. I was wondering if anyone managed to get the old MacBooks working with a Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI adapter, with HDMI 2.0. Also, should I try using a Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI connector?

Comment: Spec sheet for that monitor at https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-27-4k-uhd-usb-c-monitor-s2722qc/apd/210-bbqt/monitors-monitor-accessories#techspecs_section says it supports DP over USB-C.

Comment: Your MBP has an HDMI port, and the Dell has 2x HDMI ports. Have you considered this connection?